# How to filter Sql table on the basis of CSV column

Tags: sql-server, csv, filter

How to filter an SQL table on the basis of a VALUE that exist in its CSV column.
In detail, I have a table that has a CSV column containing integer number in comma separated form like

```
12,234,32,55 
121,64,43,65
54,25,112,12
996,612,55,3  etc.
```

now from this table I want to find out the rows that has the value 12(twelve) in csv Column i.e., the row with csv record

```
12,234,32,55
54,25,112,12 only
```

Please Help

Comment: It would be better to redesign your schema so that each value was stored in a separate row. You're not meant to stuff multiple values into a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select *
from Tablex 
where 
(Col like '%,12,%') 
 or (Col = '12')
 or LEFT(Col,3)='12,'
 or RIGHT(col,3)=',12'
```

or better as Love2Learn suggested

```
 Select * From Tablex Where ','+Col+',' Like '%,12,%'
```

Comment: You can do this to simplify it... Select * From Tablex Where ','+Col+',' Like '%,12,%'

Comment: Thanks @Love2Learn, it works perfectly...
Can u please post it as answer, so i can accept it... :-)

Comment: Also thanks @bummi for your answer... it works too but a bit difficult to understand for me

Comment: @bummi answer is more or less the same. Bummi, can you update your answer to the shortened form so OP can accept your answer?